# Scheduler module not working even after cron run

Tags: 7, cron

Installed 'Scheduler module' and try to publish a content on specific time. But it seems like it is not working.

I tried with  'Run cron manually' also, But it doesn't ,While trying with Scheduler light weight cron it is working.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

Step: 1[image: Refer this image]. First of all u have to uncheck the published node content types..

Then u have to set the schedular time for particular node [image: Refer this image]

Then U can use [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to publish.

Comment: Thanks,I will try rules module But why it is not working on cron run as suggested by drupal?